# Yampa value switch

Tags: haskell, sdl, yampa

I have an event `SF Input (Event ())` that represents the key-up of the space key. I have some `gravity` and every time the user releases the key, it must switch between `1` and `(-1)`. So I did this:

```
gravity <- accumHold 1 <<< (arr $ tag (*(-1))) <<< keyUp SDLK_SPACE -< ev
```

But what it does is switching the value up and down on repeate until I press the key again. I have no idea where I did wrong there.

The full source is found [here](https://github.com/scan/ponyv), maybe someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer is to use a switch:

```
gravity = dir 1
dir x = switch (constant x &&& keyUp SDLK_SPACE) (const (dir (-x)))
```

This is certainly also possible without a switch by mapping over the event values, but the switch seems to be the natural solution.  You can also use [Netwire](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/netwire), which makes this a lot simpler:

```
hold (iterateW negate 1 . keyUp SDLK_SPACE)
```

The `iterateW` wire will be available in Netwire 4.  Until then you can write it this way:

```
hold (accum 1 . pure negate . keyUp SDLK_SPACE)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but your `dir x` solution seems to lead to a space leak with an eternal loop (I mean, 100% CPU and my RAM is eaten up). I have not considered Netwire, does it work well with SDL or do I have to re-write that part?

Comment: It seems that working into Netwire could take ages due to the lack of adaption and documentation...

Comment: This seems to work for Yampa: `dir x = accumHold x <<< (arr $ tagWith negate) <<< edge <<< keyPressed SDLK_SPACE`